# android fingerprint sensor API

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api, samsung-galaxy

for a project at work, I'm trying to get the status (working or defective) of a fingerprint sensor on android devices to see if it works properly.

I'm using the "isHardwareDetected" function in [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html) android 6.0 API (APK 23).

Does anyone knows how the operating system gets this information about the fingerprint sensor propriety without involving the user?

i have a cell phone (Note 4) with working fingerprint sensor that gets false from isHardwareDetected and i cant explain why.

thanks,
Maor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of investigating it seams that Samsung did not implement the Android Fingerprint API support for some of their devices, thus the FingerprintManager Class wont respond as intended. I suggest using the Samsung PASS SDK which can be found here : http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass.

Related Links : [Android M FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected() returns false on a Samsung Galaxy S5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935959/android-m-fingerprintmanager-ishardwaredetected-returns-false-on-a-samsung-gal)

[FingerPrint API isHardwareDetected always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764937/fingerprint-api-ishardwaredetected-always-returns-false)

Comment: Thanks very much. problem solved. Do you know about more Android devices with the same issue?

Comment: From what I've tested and researched it seams that the issue is limited to S5 and Note4. But I can't say for sure if it these are the only devices with the problem.
Here you can follow the latest release notes from the Samsung Developer page for updates : http://developer.samsung.com/release-note/view.do?v=R000000009

Comment: Do I understand correctly from here that Samsung Pass’s API no longer works on not only newer but any up to date device? (See “note”.) https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass Wondering if I should add support for it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Android system services includes the `FingerprintManager`:

```
FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager)getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
```

You need to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

For more on how to handle the FingerprintManager read this:

[How to use fingerprint scanner to authenticate users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661608/how-to-use-fingerprint-scanner-to-authenticate-users)

Comment: thanks for the response. I already have all the permission required, and I'm not trying to authenticate users, just to understand how the operating system gets the information about the propriety of the fingerprint sensor itself.